# Passing the `...` argument to lapply

Tags: r, arguments, lapply

I am having trouble writing a function that takes `...` as an argument and then has `lapply(..., length)` in the body of the function.

Currently, my code is (the important part is in line 2):

```
paste1 <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL) {
    if(isTRUE(unique(as.logical(lapply(X = ..., FUN = length)))))
        if(length(sep)) paste(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse)
        else paste0(..., collapse = collapse)
    else
        ""
}
```

The trouble is the `lapply(X = ..., FUN = length)` part. If I have more than one element in the `...` argument, it tries to apply `length` to all of the argument at once, which throws an error as `length` only has one argument.

I cannot use something like `lapply(X = as.list(...), FUN = length)` because some of the elements of `...` may be `NULL` and the list representation of `...` will have lost information.

All I need to do is apply `length` to the individual elements of `...` without coercing them first.

Comment: Use `list` instead of `as.list`?

Comment: Can you show an example input/use? I can't reproduce your issue if I do `dots <- list(...)` then `lapply(dots, length)`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that `list` differed from `as.list`.

Comment: @JonClaus I don't even see that `as.list(...)` can even work - fails for me.

Comment: Do you mean that it throws an error or that it does not work as expected? It seemed to work for me (meaning it didn't throw errors), but I didn't test it much as I already knew it would fail in some circumstances.

Comment: It throws error `Error in as.list.default(x = ...) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: What happens without the `X =` part, i.e. `as.list.default(...)`.

Comment: @JonClaus I didn't do that. Try `foo <- function(...) as.list(...)` with `foo(A = 10)` and you'll get that error. It is method dispatch that results in `as.list.default(x = ...)` being called like that and that gives the error. But I only ever used `as.list(...)`.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve and you code is quite obfuscated. I think instead of `isTRUE(unique(as.logical(...))` you perhaps want `all(... > 0)`.  And why are you inspecting the `length` of sep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version uses `dots <- list(...)` which seems not to fail on this input:

```
> paste1(A = "foo", B = NULL, C = c("bar","foo"))
[1] ""
```

I haven't looked at what your function is trying to do nor whether this is valid input, but `lapply(X = dots, FUN = length)` does what you want and `dots <- list(...)` preserves the `NULL`.

```
paste1 <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL) {
    dots <- list(...)
    if(isTRUE(unique(as.logical(lapply(X = dots, FUN = length)))))
        if(length(sep)) paste(dots, sep = sep, collapse = collapse)
        else paste0(dots, collapse = collapse)
    else
        ""
}
```

Comment: Are there any `as.list` methods that actually use the `...` argument? I can't seem to find any that do. Is it there just for "future" options?

Comment: Indeed - I couldn't reproduce the issue the OP mentioned as `as.list()` just errored out.